# Different OPE channels in bootstrap

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

Can someone quickly explain what exactly are those different channels (namely s,t,u) in OPE expansions frequently used in conformal bootstrap. Explanation with a simple example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the four point function $\langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_3)\phi(x_4)\rangle$, the conformal block expansion depends on what operators you replace by the OPE. So if you insert the OPE for $\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$ and the OPE for $\phi(x_3)\phi(x_4)$ then this corresponds to the s channel---one can also call this the (12)(34) channel---.. The t channel is then the (14)(23) channel and u is the (13)(24) channel.